# EF4.1 error on one machine and not on another

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, 32bit-64bit, entity-framework-4.1, cassini

I am getting this error on one PC but not on another. Both are connecting to a local SQLExpress 2008 R2 database which is identical on both machines. Both machines have VS2010 SP1 and EF4.1 (included in the tools update). It is an MVC3 Web Application project running in Cassini:

[NotSupportedException: Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.]

I can't for the life of me work out why this is the case - it happens at the `Attach()` below:

```
IQueryable<Tag> tags = db.Tags.Where(x => !tagIds.Contains(x.Id) && x.Questions.Any(y => y.Id == question.Id));
question.Tags.Attach(tags);
```

The only difference I can think of is that one machine is 32-bit and the other 64, but I don't know how to determine if this is the problem for any reason.

Any ideas?

TIA

Comment: Is the code you have posted wrapped in an `if` or something that might prevent it from executing on the machine that "it works" on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data in the two local databases was not the same, which meant that `tagIds` returned null on one machine and not on the other. The error message isn't very helpful but that was what caused it.

Using `Contains` in this scenario is fine in EF4.

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem would be the `x => !tagIds.Contains(x.Id)` as the "Contains" cannot be translated to T-SQL by EF. Try searching on the exception for more information.

Comment: why would that work in one scenario though and not another? (seemingly based on post)

Comment: The error is pretty characteristic of a failure to parse the lambda. I suspect the code isn't actually running on the one machine and therefore does not fail.